# Pass values to some StringEdit from a form to another form on Dynamics ax 2012

Tags: c#, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I dont have idea how to fill StringEdit text from Init where I catch values from a method in another form, please help me :c

Here the click method in the first form

```
void clicked()
{
    Args args;
    FormRun formRun;
    BBP_TableClientes _BBP_TableClientes;
    BBP_ClassesPuntoDeVenta _BBP_ClassesPuntoDeVenta;
    super();
    args = new args(formstr(BBP_NuevaVenta));
    args.record(BBP_TableClientes);
    formrun = classfactory.formrunclass(args);
    formrun.init();
    formrun.run();
    formrun.wait();
    formrun.detach();
}
```

and here the init in the other form

```
public void init()
{
    BBP_TableClientes _BBP_TableClientes1;
    super();
    _BBP_TableClientes1 = element.args().record();
    BBP_TableClientes_ds.query().dataSourceTable(Tablenum(BBP_TableClientes)).addRange(fieldNum(BBP_TableClientes,ID_Cliente)).
    value(SysQuery::value(_BBP_TableClientes1.ID_Cliente));
}
```

I fill a table with that source but I want to fill some StringEdit with that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass between forms just a simple string you can use 'parm' method of 'Args' class:

```
args.parm("My text");
```

Than you need to set property `AutoDeclaration` on your ***StringEdit control*** to `Yes`,

[image]

after that you will be able refer it by name and set the value:

```
StringEdit.text("My text");
StringEdit.text(element.args().parm());
StringEdit.text(_BBP_TableClientes1.ID_Cliente);
```

Comment: I already did AutoDeclaration but when I put this code on init method trows me a error StringEdit.text("hello"); <-- the StringEdit was not declarated, and the init method is not a method of edition/visualisation

Comment: Change `StringEdit.text("hello");` for your String Control Edit Name, the name of `StringEdit` is in properties of this control. Example: `YourStringEditName.text("hello");`

Comment: Thanks so much guys, as you can see I'm really new with Dynamics, I'm taking a small course and simple things like this take me a loot of time to found, now I hunderstand a little bit more :D Thank you !! Have a good day ! @JonathanBravetti